# Won't boot into 15.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, 15.04

I tried updating to 15.04 and while booting, it failed midstream.  Last thing it says is "Started LSB:  Tool to automatically collect and submit kernal crash signatures....ut down.."

In February I got a Republic of Gamers motherboard (Maximus VII Hero).  Boot would fail 1 of 5 times, but it would generally work the second time.  After updating, it won't boot at all.

Any clues would be really helpful...

Dan